# How to reshape a numpy array into 3 dimensional for input to convolutional layer?

Tags: pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, conv-neural-network

[image: current situation of x_train array]

I have x_train array which is of 235 elements  and each element is a numpy array of rows 125 and 125 columns . I neeed this array to be in shape of (235,125,125) so as to feed to my convolutional neural network model ((((similar to case when we need to feed MNIST digit array of (6000,28,28) where we have 60000 samples each of which is 28x28 array)))

Can someone tell how to reshape the x_train array to (235,125,125) ?

P.S I initially converted x_train from pandas series to numpy array below is the snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Numpy's `reshape` command:

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 125, 125, 1)
```

Have a look at [this part of](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py#L26) Keras' MNIST CNN tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `np.newaxis` as follows:

```
x_train [...,np.newaxis]
```

And you will the shape will be:

```
x_train [...,np.newaxis].shape
(235, 125, 125, 1)
```